# Prove that normal lines to a cylinder cut the axis perpendicularly

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, tangent-spaces

Consider the following problem (Exercise 2.55 in Montiel and Ros's *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition):

> Let $S = \{p \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ |p|^2 - \langle p, a \rangle^2  = r^2\}$, with $|a|=1$ and $r>0$, be a right cylinder of radius $r$ whose axis is the line passing through the origin with direction $a$. Prove that $T_pS = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ \langle p, v \rangle - \langle p, a \rangle \langle a, v \rangle = 0\}$. Conclude that all the normal lines of $S$ cut the axis perpendicularly.

Now, $S = f^{-1}(r^2)$ where $f(p) = |p|^2 - \langle p, a \rangle^2$. But 
$$
(df)_p[v] = 2 \langle p, v \rangle - 2 \langle p, a \rangle \langle a, v \rangle, 
$$
hence the first part.

Now, How to show the second part?

Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just observe that $a\in T_p(S)$ and the orthogonal projection  $p_{\perp a}:=p-\langle p, a\rangle\, a\, \perp T_p(S)$.

Comment: This intersection part is where I am having more trouble, could you develop, please?

Comment: One way is to consider the orthogonal projection $p_{\perp a}$ of $p$ to $a$ and prove that it's the normal vector. Geometrically, you can argue that the points $0,\,p_{\perp a},\,p,\,a$ are coplanar.

Comment: You mean $p - p_{\perp a}$?

Comment: It depends on the notation. What I thought is $p=p_{\perp a}+p_{\parallel a}$ with $p_{\perp a}\perp a$. Doesn't matter. By the way, for the first read I thought the question is only about orthogonality, actually intersection is indeed a bit harder to argue.

Comment: So, let us fix the notation as $p_{\perp a} = p - \langle p, a \rangle a$ (as you used it). I am to show that $p_{\perp a}$ is orthogonal to every $v \in T_pS$. This is trivial, because taking inner products we get that it is identically zero. Are we done?

Comment: Yes, the point $p_{\parallel a}$ is on the axis, and the line through it parallel to $p_{\perp a}$ goes through $p$.

Comment: I adjusted my hint to include the intersection part at once.